# Apuntador de Apuntador en C++, cual es la finalidad de esto?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy aprendiendo de forma autodidacta C++, estoy ahora en el tema de punteros, y todo bien, sin embargo, cuando vi el apuntador de apuntadores me confundí un poco. Dejare aquí el código, y lo que entendi:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int **tabla;
   int n = 134;
   int m = 231;
   int i;

   // Array de punteros a int:
   tabla = new int*[n];
   // n arrays de m ints
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      tabla[i] = new int[m];

   tabla[21][33] = 123;
   cout << tabla[21][33] << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Lo que entendi aquí fue que establecemos un apuntador que apuntara a otro apuntador, es por eso que declaramos con `**` en la variable de tipo puntero `int` llamada tabla. Luego definimos unas variables de tipo `int` y sus respectivos valores. Luego se establece `tabla = new int*[n]` ya aquí no lo entiendo. ¿Qué significa `int*[n]`? luego se realiza un bucle for estableciendo me parece que por índice un `int[m]` no entiendo tampoco su funcionalidad.

Finalmente le decimos a tabla que almacene en `[21][33]`n el valor 123, eso si lo comprendo e igual al imprimir el valor. Lo que no entiendo es que significa `int*[n];` y `tabla[i] = new int[m]` en el bucle. Lo ultimo seria saber cual es la funcionalidad de usar un apuntador que apunte a otro apuntador. Tengo entendido que es para algo de matrices, pero no comprendí bien. Cualquier ayuda me vendria bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Qué significa `int*[n]`?

Para responder, vamos a dividir la sentencia en partes:

```
//       _____ Formación de 'n' elementos de tipo 'int*'
//      /
//     /
// vvvvvvvv
   int* [n]
// ^^^^ ^^^
//   \    \
//    \    \_____ Tamaño de la formación (n)
//     \
//      \_____ Tipo de dato: puntero (*) a entero (int)
```

Lo qué significa `int*[n]` es: formación<sup>1</sup> de `n` elementos de tipo `int*`.

Las formaciones multidimensionales necesitan punteros a punteros por la manera en que se organizan los datos en memoria, imagina que tienes una tabla de 3×3:

```
         columnas
           |
           v
         +---+---+---+
filas -> | 0 | 1 | 2 |
         +---+---+---+
         | 3 | 4 | 5 |
         +---+---+---+
         | 6 | 7 | 8 |
         +---+---+---+
```

Cada fila, está formada por tres elementos ¿De qué manera [c](/questions/tagged/c) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) organizan colecciones de datos? Con formaciones, así que cada fila es una formación de tres elementos (que serán las columnas).

```
                  +---+---+---+
1ª fila (int*) -> | 0 | 1 | 2 |
                  +---+---+---+

                  +---+---+---+
2ª fila (int*) -> | 3 | 4 | 5 |
                  +---+---+---+

                  +---+---+---+
3ª fila (int*) -> | 6 | 7 | 8 |
                  +---+---+---+
```

Para apuntar a un dato de un tipo, necesitas un puntero a ese tipo; este puntero no es más que el nombre del tipo acompañado de un asterisco:

```
int i;     // Número entero (int).
int *pi;   // Puntero (*) a número entero (int).
float f;   // Número en coma flotante (float) de precisión simple.
float *pf; // Puntero (*) a número en coma flotante (float) de precisión simple.
```

Por lo tanto, si cada fila es una colección de elementos apuntados por un puntero a entero (`int*`) para apuntar a una fila necesitas un puntero a un puntero a entero (`int**`). De la misma manera, al usar el operador de indizado (los corchetes `[]`) sobre un puntero, obtienes un elemento en la posición indicada, este elemento será del tipo del puntero pero sin el puntero, suponiendo una tabla de 3×3 llamada `tabla`:

```
int *primera_fila = tabla[0];
int *segunda_fila = tabla[1];
int *tercera_fila = tabla[2];
```

La tabla necesita apuntar a filas, cada fila necesita apuntar a enteros. Así que cada fila será un puntero a entero (`int*`) y la tabla será un puntero a filas, es decir un puntero a puntero a entero (`int*`).

> Lo que no entiendo es que significa `int*[n];` y `tabla[i] = new int[m]` en el bucle.

Cuando creas un puntero, el puntero no apunta a ningún sitio válido. Para que apunte a un sitio válido debes darle una dirección de memoria a la que apuntar. Lo que hace el operador `new` es reservar un espacio de memoria para un dato del tipo solicitado, así pues la instrucción:

```
new int[m];
```

Reserva espacio para almacenar `m` datos de tipo `int` y devuelve un puntero (`int*`) al inicio de la zona de memoria en que ese espacio fue reservado. En resumen y paso por paso:

```
// Un puntero a puntero a entero (int**) para crear una formación bidimensional.
int **tabla;

// Reservamos 'n' filas. Al pedir memoria (new) para punteros a entero (int*) recibiremos
// un puntero a un espacio de memoria que almacenará 'n' punteros a entero (int*), el puntero
// será para apuntar a 'int*' por lo tanto será 'int**'.
tabla = new int*[n];

// Dado que las filas aún no apuntan a ningún sitio válido, debemos asignar memoria fila a fila:
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   // Reservamos 'm' elementos. Al pedir memoria (new) para enteros (int) recibiremos
   // un puntero a un espacio de memoria que almacenará 'm' enteros (int), el puntero
   // será para apuntar a 'int' por lo tanto será 'int*'.
   tabla[i] = new int[m];
```

Llegados a este punto, olvida todo lo escrito hasta ahora. En C++ moderno se aconseja **no usar** punteros en crudo y se aconseja evitar el uso de `new` a no ser que sea absolutamente necesario. Tu código puede reescribirse para no usar punteros:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using fila_t = std::vector<int>;
    using tabla_t = std::vector<fila_t>;

    int n = 134;
    int m = 231;
    // Tabla de 'm' filas de 'n' elementos cada una.
    tabla_t tabla(m, fila_t(n));

    tabla[21][33] = 123;
    std::cout << tabla[21][33] << '\n';

    return 0;
};
```

Si evitas el uso de `new` y el abuso de punteros, tu código será más compacto, más claro, menos propenso a errores y te evitas gestionar la memoria manualmente. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoIwEEXX9BSTuAASTYS6gspFkJhaKmkCAymtG@PZawsSY@Jq8v@8NyOm6SB6jp1zO4Wit60EpsbZaMmHiny7hxRm1BUhCg0MXGGSwpNEdlbYwV31/GrgDLNpi2JFmQerciMMv/1BVs9TJApn0a8zeirXNPiU08ynTV5mMuw//xJM06AudZ1nTU1pE07k1EvLHzFaA4zBL@KL@IJxcLU0ViMcS/IqnXsD)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Hola PaperBirdMaster. Explicaste excelente, y ya puse tu respuesta como la correcta para tu reputacion. Sin embargo, te hare otra pregunta, para estar seguro. En la parte del bucle que dice: tabla[i] = new int[m]; entendi basado en tu respuesta, que... Se asigna un espacio en memoria con [i] para cada fila, donde [m] es la cantidad de elementos que tendra no? quedando por ejemplo si m = 3, n = 3, entonces habrian 3 filas (por n), y esas 3 filas tendran una capacidad de 3 elementos de tipo int para almacenar numeros enteros. Quedando una tabla 3x3 estoy bien?

Comment: @AndreLopez Ciertamente entendiste bien :) pero insisto en que no uses `new` ni punteros.

Comment: Sí, eso haré. Muchas gracias PaperBirdMaster.